# Error: Cannot find module 'tslint/lib/lint' when trying to extend tslint-microsoft-contrib

Tags: typescript, tslint

This is our environment

```
> \node_modules\.bin\tslint --version
4.0.1

> npm install --save-dev tslint-microsoft-contrib
`-- tslint-microsoft-contrib@2.0.13
```

This is our tslint.json configuration.

```
{
    "extends": [
        "./node_modules/tslint-microsoft-contrib/tslint.json"
    ]
}
```

This is what happens when we run our local `tslint` with that configuration.

```
> node_modules\.bin\tslint --config .\tslint.json --project .\tsconfig.json
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'tslint/lib/lint'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\myApp\node_modules\tslint-microsoft-contrib\insecureRandomRule.js:7:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

How can we run `tslint` on a configuration that extends `tslint-microsoft-contrib`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to downgrade to tslint 3.x.x, tslint-microsoft-contrib doesn't yet support tslint 4, PR [#314](https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib/pull/314) should fix that, the PR looks done, but the tests require grunt-tslint to be upgraded to support tslint 4 as well. For the mean time, you can continue to use tslint@3

Comment: Haha. My pleasure Shaun.