# tslint update error "Cannot find module 'tslint/lib/lint'"

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, tslint

We recently upgraded our Angular 2 project to `@angular/cli` version 1.0.  We also upgraded `tslint` from `2.x` to `5.x`.  Now we receive the following `tslint` error at design time (in VSCode Output terminal).

> Cannot find module 'tslint/lib/lint' while validating.

I've attempted to follow several github thread suggestions including removing deprecated rules and adding new rules, rolling back `tslint` to a previous version and completely uninstalling and reinstalling `@angular/cli` and associated modules.

However, this error continues to arise and it's preventing `tslint` from evaluating our code.

A previous SO post cited the same error message but apparently for a different reason; the accepted answer did not resolve my issue:
[Error: Cannot find module 'tslint/lib/lint' when trying to extend tslint-microsoft-contrib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749996/error-cannot-find-module-tslint-lib-lint-when-trying-to-extend-tslint-microso?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue: `codelyzer` was out of date.  I updated it from `0.0.26` to `2.1.1` and now `tslint` is successfully linting our code.

> npm update codelyzer --save-dev

Answer (score 2):

For installing tslint simple command is :

```
npm install tslint --save 


 npm install codelyzer --save
```

For angular: tslint installation command :

```
npm i tslint-angular --save
```

For typescript: tslint installation command :

```
 npm install -g tslint typescript --save
```